# Tem como abrir excel no delphi sem Excel instalado;

Tags: delphi, microsoft-excel

Estou dando suporte a um sistema que o programador fez uso de OleObject para abrir e ler um arquivo Excel
Acontece que eu trabalho com o brOffice e o delphi da erro quando tento abrir excel porque o objeto ole precisa do excel instalado.
Procurei na web e vi que alguns sugerem a inclusão da uses ComObj, já incluí mas o mesmo erro continua.

```
---------------------------
Debugger Exception Notification
---------------------------
Project perfil.exe raised exception class EOleSysError with message 'Cadeia de caracteres de classe inválida'.
---------------------------
Break   Continue   Help   
---------------------------
```

Pesquisando vi que a unica forma é instalar o excel mesmo!

A rotina usada pra abrir o arquivo é:

```
class function TFuncoes.XlsToStringGrid(AGrid: TStringGrid; AXLSFile: string):
  Boolean;
const
  xlCellTypeLastCell = $0000000B;
var
  XLApp, Sheet: OLEVariant;
  RangeMatrix: Variant;
  x, y, k, R: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  // Cria Excel- OLE Object
  XLApp := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  try
    // Esconde Excel
    XLApp.Visible := False;
    // Abre o Workbook
    XLApp.Workbooks.Open(AXLSFile);
    Sheet := XLApp.Workbooks[ExtractFileName(AXLSFile)].WorkSheets[1];
    Sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell, EmptyParam).Activate;
    // Pegar o número da última linha
    x := XLApp.ActiveCell.Row;
    // Pegar o número da última coluna
    y := XLApp.ActiveCell.Column;
    // Seta Stringgrid linha e coluna
    AGrid.RowCount := x;
    AGrid.ColCount := y;
    // Associaca a variant WorkSheet com a variant do Delphi
    RangeMatrix := XLApp.Range['A1', XLApp.Cells.Item[x, y]].Value;
    // Cria o loop para listar os registros no TStringGrid
    k := 1;
    repeat
      for R := 1 to y do
        AGrid.Cells[(R - 1), (k - 1)] := RangeMatrix[k, R];
      Inc(k, 1);
    until k > x;
    RangeMatrix := Unassigned;
  finally
    // Fecha o Excel
    if not VarIsEmpty(XLApp) then
    begin
      XLApp.Quit;
      XLApp := Unassigned;
      Sheet := Unassigned;
      Result := true;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

A função funciona em maquinas que possuem excel.

Eu não queria ter que instalar o excel na minha maquina de desenvolvimento.

Alguém sugere outra opção para ler esses arquivos? (não posso trocar por outro tipo de arquivo, pois os mesmos vem de terceiros)

Comment: Se quiser trabalhar com o BROffice, o melhor seria trabalhar com a versão mais recente do LibreOffice, você terá que utilizar os objetos do LibreOffice e não do Excel. Tais objetos são diferentes no dois softwares.

Comment: Eu uso o LibreOffice tambem, porem a empresa que usa o ERP não usa, ai fico numa sinuca de bico, tenho que comprar um excel só pra dar suporte... ai fica dificil :) se tiver uma alternativa sem envolver a empresa.

Comment: Se o cliente usa determinado software e você vende seus serviços de suporte a este cliente precisa ter os softwares que ele utiliza.

Comment: Meu sistema não precisa necessariamente do Excel, isso foi uma solicitação dele, na verdade era pra o sistema ler um arquivo CNAB que é tipo texto, mas a preguiça do cliente em falar com o gerente para disponibilizar este arquivo na area de cliente do banco acabou me gerando esse contratempo, para ajudar o cliente acabou-se lendo um arquivo excel mesmo sem um padrão, agora ele mudou de banco e quer manter o arquivo, pois o outro banco tambem usa, mas com outro layout, já avisei pra ele que o correto é arquivos CNAB, a gente vai ajudar e cai nessas

Comment: Isso é a maior "gambi". Vai de CNAB mesmo, quanto mais remenda mais piora. ou entao salve em CSV, que é texto puro.

Comment: @Bacco aqui optamos por isto, não importamos nada de xls, implementamos apenas csv. Muita canseira no lado do software/desenvolvimento quando a simplicidade em salvar em outro formato esta a dois cliques na mão do usuário.

Comment: Pior que o sistema esta cheio dessas POGs, eu já falei pra ele pegar os CNAB, mas sabe-se lá quando vou ter esses arquivos, por enquanto não tenho outra opção a não ser remendar, eu consegui baixar uma versão do office no site da microsoft que não é travada (pode ser que trave depois), com ela instalada consegui abrir os arquivos pelo delphi, chama-se Office365proplus - é um release para testadores, mas pro meu caso esta ótima :) - Eu não instalo essas versões piratas por aí porque estão cheias de vírus.

Answer (score -1):

Recomendo usar outro tipo de dados como disse "Bacco"
Exemplo:Json, XML, CSV, desse jeito você manipula e não fica refém de Microsoft nem LibreOffice.

E você comprando o componente da "TMS" seria um **Trade-off**, ainda continuaria refém, sem falar do valor, Licença Office(Microsoft) X Licença TMS(TMS).

É trocar Licença por outra Licença.

**Usa dados simples e com fácil manipulação.**